# How to Run Test file of java in Spring Framework

Tags: java, xml, spring, eclipse, spring-framework-beans

This is my first Springframework Programme using java and i'm facing this issue . Hope you guys help me.
Thank you

Expected Result:
Hello Sunil Singh

// my Test.java shows error as

```
    Error: Could not find or load main class firstspring.Test
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: firstspring.Test
```

// Student.java file

```
 package firstspring;

public class Student {

private String name;  
  
public String getName() {  
    return name;  
}  
  
public void setName(String name) {  
    this.name = name;  
}  
  
public void displayInfo(){  
    System.out.println("Hello: "+name);  
    
       }  
    }
```

// applicationContext.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <beans  
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

    <bean id="studentbean" class="/firstspring/src/firstspring/Student.java">  
    <property name="name" value="Sunil Singh"></property>  
    </bean>  

    </beans>
```

// Test.java file

```
    package firstspring;


    import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;  
    import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
    import org.springframework.core.io.Resource; 

    public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  
      
    Student student=(Student)factory.getBean("studentbean");  
    student.displayInfo();  
     }  
    }
```

//  using Referenced Libraries

```
    spring-core-5.3.20.jar
```

Comment: There's no @SpringApplication annotation. Please go through a proper Spring Boot Tutorial before using Spring

Comment: @justanotherguy he is using plain Spring not Spring Boot. So advicing to add spring boot related annotations won't help.

Comment: Your class isn't found which means it probably isn't compiled. How are you running/compiling things.

Comment: using eclipse ide and running as java application

Comment: Are there any errors for your Test class in the Problems view?

Comment: yes the error are  : Error:  Could not find or load main class firstspring.  Test
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: firstspring.Test

Comment: Add the directories to the filenames in this question.